# Failed to install Gnome-Shell-Extensions: Missing Separator

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, git

I'm trying to install gnome-shell-extensions in terminal using these instructions:

> > - Download Gnome Shell extensions by running following command: git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-shell-extensions
> > - Now access the directory from terminal by running following command: cd gnome-shell-extensions/
> > - Finally run this command to install the extension: ./autogen.sh --prefix=$HOME/.local --enable-extensions="user-theme"

source: http://www.noobslab.com/2011/10/beautiful-tron-legacy-and-aqua-themes.html

When I go to 'make' however, I get the following error:

```
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/z3r0/gnome-shell-extensions/extensions'
    Making all in user-theme
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/z3r0/gnome-shell-extensions/extensions/user-theme'
    Makefile:442: *** missing separator.  Stop.
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/z3r0/gnome-shell-extensions/extensions/user-theme'
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/z3r0/gnome-shell-extensions/extensions'
    make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I've tried adding a TAB to line 442 in:

- /home/z3r0/gnome-shell-extensions/Makefile
- /home/z3r0/gnome-shell-extensions/extensions/Makefile

using gedit, but both files don't save with the changes.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about gnome-shell-extensions, it is better to install gnome-tweak-tool and then open https://extensions.gnome.org in web browser and add your favorite extensions just by one click!